# C# asp.net cclick event fires twice

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a click event in C# code behind file that sends an e-mail, everything works fine except that it sends the email twice.

I tried the recommended solution and set `AutoEventWireup="false"`, this does nothing it still sends the email twice.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Set `<% @Page AutoEventWireup="true" %>` to `false`.

```
protected void cmdNotify_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    newmail = new mymail();
    newmail.SendMail();
}
```

Email sends twice.

Comment: post the .aspx code

Comment: Thanks here is the aspx code
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Index.aspx.cs" Inherits="WillisOp.Index" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Maintenance</title>
    <link href="content/gridStyle1.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
</head>

Comment: Search for that cmdNotify_Click in your source code. Where is it used? Set a breakpoint inside it, is it really called twice?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why people suggest you turn `AutoEventWireup` off. Don't do that unless you want to manually wire up events. For example, you need to write the following line to have any code in the `Page_Load` event handler executed when the page is requested:

`Load += new EventHandler(Page_Load);`

So, let `AutoEventWireup` to its default value (`true`) and make sure no such code exists in your code behind.

Another important thing to understand is that this has not to do with sending the email per se but with the life cycle of your page. You may have code in `Page_Load` that triggers  the mail sending code or even JavaScript code that raises the event. Make sure this is not the case by cleaning up your code. For example, you may want to start over with the following sample page which demonstrates that normally button click events are raised only once per request and gradually add your code to it:

**ASPX**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Code behind**

```
namespace WebApplication1
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        private static int times = 0;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            times++;
            Label1.Text = times.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps. I am using Visual Studio 2017 and the target framework is .NET Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: dpant:
Thanks, i set autoeventwireup back to true and tried your example ts definitely firing twice, I can't see any other code (such as in page_load ) that would be doing this??
Not sure what to do now, other than going back to winforms, what a mess

Comment: @RobD If you add `newmail.SendMail();` in the above sample `Button1_Click` method and it sends the email twice while there is absolutely no other interfering code (any JavaScript?) then your last and most unlikely chance is to check how `mymail` class really works. You may also update your question with a full sample (as the one I've posted) to let us help you further.